# Unhandled exception type Interrupted Exception when Thread.sleep(xxxx) is given

Tags: selenium-webdriver

If Thread.sleep(3000); code is given, it throws an error as

> "Unhandled exception type Interrupted Exception".

Mouse hover to the error, it is displaying as "Surround with try/catch". By double clicking it i am getting as below and wworking fine. Kindly say me the difference of both.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Flagged as it is not appropriate for SQA. This is a general coding question. And it is a duplicate which can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703324/why-do-i-need-to-handle-an-exception-for-thread-sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(ms)` throws an exception as you are trying to interuption in thread execution

It may throw `InterruptedException` which directly extends `java.lang.Exception` so you have to catch it or declare to throw it.

so that we have to use the try-catch

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```